# Redisson RLocalCachedMap behavior with data obtained prior to a invalidate

Tags: java, redis, redisson

We are using Redisson RLocalCachedMap so we can speed up reads. It's configured with TTLs and INVALIDATE policy.

And we have many processes doing something like this:

```
...
RLocalCachedMap<String, Set<MyPojo>> rCacheMap = whateverGivesMeTheMap("pojo-cache");

Collection<Pojo> myCollection = rCacheMap.get(key);

process(myCollection);
...
```

The question: if an invalidate occurs after `rCacheMap.get(key)`, **does the myCollection object remains unchanged no matter what happens with cache?** I bet the answer is affirmative, so you won't get fresh data until you call rCacheMap.get(key) again. But I would like to be sure of that. If not, we should do a copy of the collection and work on it.

I did some research for this on Redisson docs / google / stackoverflow without success.

Maybe this seems a crazy question or obvious, but I now Redisson does some magic with live objects, etc. BTW Hazelcast clarifies this subject in it's documentation for IMap get operation (https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0/javadoc/com/hazelcast/map/IMap.html)

Thanks!

Comment: I can't give a definite answer here but I assume that when there is a cache update, i.e. a new set is stored in the cache, this will be a new object. As far as I know `RLocalCachedMap` doesn't make any asumptions about the value type and thus can't make copies or updates. So you probably will get the collection that's in the cache, which will get replaced rather than updated. However, if multiple parts of your code get the same cached set I also assume those will share the instance so I would always make a defensive copy.

Comment: We are currently doing this defensive copy, but this is a very big project and I wonder if we can get rid of these copies to save some heap space, GC events, etc. Sry but I don't get your point after "However" word, if a replace of the value instead of an update is the most probable, there is definitively no need to do the copy. Because my reference (myCollection) points to the older object.

Comment: On the "however" part: think about service A getting the collection from the cache and service B getting the same (no update happenend in between). They now have a reference to the same collection and thus if A changes it, B will see those changes (and the cache might see those as well).